# Order PHP array by sub-array by date key

Tags: php, arrays

I know this question has been asked a hundred times, and I've gone through multiple answers and am not getting the correct results.

I am trying to order the following row by date, oldest first:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => '3173'
        [1] => 'Contact - 12-6-14 Outstanding invoice'
        [2] => '16/06/2014'
        [3] => '204'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => '3167'
        [1] => 'Contact - Outstanding invoice'
        [2] => '13/06/2014'
        [3] => '207'
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => '3497'
        [1] => 'New Site - Keri Keri'
        [2] => '25/11/2014'
        [3] => '43'
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => '2023'
        [1] => 'Analysis'
        [2] => '17/06/2014'
        [3] => '355'
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => '2641'
        [1] => 'PSS'
        [2] => '20/02/2014'
        [3] => '321'
    )
```

)

I have tried things such as the below with no luck.

```
function cmp($a, $b){
      return $b[2] - $a[2];
   } 

usort($urgent_array, "cmp");
```

Any help on this one would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to compare, not subtract:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2] == $b[2])
        return 0;
    return ($a[2] > $b[2]) ? 1 : -1;
} 

usort($urgent_array, "cmp");
```

Then, date ordering works best if you use the `Y-m-d` format:

`2014-06-13` etc.

Comment: Ooops my mistake putting 2, it was 3.
Doesn't work though, the array just comes back blank

Comment: @SeánMcCabe what about the other changes - using comparison operators like `<` and `>` instead of subtracting and putting the year first?

Comment: My bad, didnt save the changes properly. Just had to swap the return condition around so it was $b[2] < $a[2] thank you :)

Comment: @SeánMcCabe my pleasure, I'll update my answer with the `>` facing the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Change your compare function to

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    $a_date = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $a[2]));
    $b_date = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $b[2]));

    return $a_date - $b_date;
}
```

You want to use strtotime because subtracting strings doesn't really mean anything. The str_replace is because PHP expects dashes for dd-mm-yyyy format.